# Flask with Asyncrounus Cronjob in the Background

Tags: python, flask

So what i am trying to do is, to host my Flask API and have a script running on the Server in the background all the time, even when there is no user that is accessing the API.

The script in the background should be executed once a minuite to update things in the Database.

Comment: Cool. Start your updater under `systemd` and let it run independently of `flask` and its users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Docker and create a ChronJob in it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

What you're interested in are "cronjobs".

You can check out a library like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) to get started. In particular, you'll want to look at [Celery "beat"](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#guide-beat).